# In npm, how are git dependencies cloned?

Tags: npm, npm-install

When you have a `git+ssh://` dependency in a `package.json`, what actually happens when you run `npm install`? Does it:

a) Use the `git` command from the OS to clone the repo? (I think this is unlikely)

b) Somehow download the files using Node APIs, without actually cloning the repo?

Bonus: how can I find the code (I assume in the NPM project) that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm uses git command of your os, you can see it by running [`npm doctor`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/doctor#which-git)

and [here is a reference in the code](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/doctor/get-git-path.js#L7)

> **which git**
>
> While it’s documented in the README, it may not be obvious that npm needs Git installed to do many of the things that it does. Also, in some cases – especially on Windows – you may have Git set up in such a way that it’s not accessible via your PATH so that npm can find it. This check ensures that Git is available.